# Error: Expression must have a constant value

Tags: c++

> Expression must have a constant value

Recibo este error en la línea `int mas[n]`. ¿Por qué se produce el error?

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter the number of elements: "; cin >> n;
    int mas[n];
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        mas[i] = rand()%100-1; 
        cout << " " << mas[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int mas[n];
```

Esto es lo que se conoce como *VLA* o "*Variable Length Array*" y es una estructura que no está permitida en el estándar de C++ (a diferencia del lenguaje C donde sí se puede usar). Un array es un *VLA* si el tamaño del arreglo no se conoce en tiempo de compilación. Si `n` fuese una constante sí podrías crear el arreglo:

```
const int n = 10;
int mas[n]; // OK
```

Lo que sucede es que al no formar parte del estándar dependerá del compilador soportar esta característica o no. En algunos compiladores el código compilará y en otros no.

Para evitar este problema puedes usar memoria dinámica:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter the number of elements: "; cin >> n;
    int* mas = new int[n];
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        mas[i] = rand()%100-1; 
        cout << " " << mas[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;

    delete[] mas;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

O un contenedor de la STL:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Enter the number of elements: "; cin >> n;
    std::vector<int> mas(n);
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        mas[i] = rand()%100-1; 
        cout << " " << mas[i] << "\t";
    }
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```